# Editing items in list view after selecting edit from menu of OncontextItemSelected

Tags: java, android

This is the code of my project where in I have a listview of objects 'mProductList'. I have set an onclickListener on each item of list view which will open a menu with three options. Now on edit i want to change the variable amount in my selected item and display it on the screen. I am new at this so please dont downvote this. Any help would be appreciated stackoverflow. Please let me k now if u need any more of my code.

```
     ProductListAdapter adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mProductList);
        lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Do something
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Clicked product id = " + view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                registerForContextMenu(lvProduct);
                openContextMenu(lvProduct);

            }
        });

    }
    final int CONTEXT_MENU_ADD =1;
    final int CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT =2;
    final int CONTEXT_MENU_ARCHIVE =3;
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        //Context menu
        menu.setHeaderTitle("My Context Menu");
        menu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_ADD, 0, "Add");
        menu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit");
        menu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_ARCHIVE, 0, "Delete");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case CONTEXT_MENU_ADD:
            {

            }
            break;
            case CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT:
            {
                // Edit Action

            }
            break;
            case CONTEXT_MENU_ARCHIVE:
            {

            }
            break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my Product class whose objects are made and displayed in the list view:

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int amount;
    //private String description;

    //Constructor

    public Product(int id, String name, int amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;

    }


    //Setter, getter

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setPrice(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
```